# How to associate exstension with program so that it works with tab complete

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I use texmaker to edit my LaTeX (.tex) documents. I also use texmaker for other things, but 90% of the time I just want to open a .tex document.

If I want to open document.tex, I usually just write `texm` and then I hit `tab` and I automatically get `texmaker`. Then I start to write `document` and when I hot `tab` I get `document.` because there are several files called document.

How can I change this so that with `tab` it will automaticall fill in `document.tex` even though there are several files called `document`?

As an example, when I do `xpdf document` and then hit `tab` I get the `.pdf` automatically even though there are several files called `document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add the following in your `.bashrc`:

```
complete -f -X '!*.tex' texmaker
```

Check [debian-administation.org](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2) and [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) for more info on the `complete` command.

Comment: Welcome.  I like the nice short concise answers :) +1

Comment: Thank you for this. A dumb question: Where is the `/bashrc` file? (or where do I put it?)

Comment: its at `home` directory , `~/.bashrc`

Comment: @Thomas it is not `/bashrc` but `~/.bashrc` were `~` denotes your home directory, usually at `/home/username`. File `.bashrc` most probably is already present there, but if it is not then you can safely create it.

Comment: @jimmij: Thanks for this. The file didn't exist, but I created it. And now it works just like I wanted! :)